# What changes in the gradle are required to use FirebaseListAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Well, I had already done a project that used `FirebaseListAdapter`, however with this recent Firebase update what modifications I have to do in my dependencies to continue using the `FirebaseListAdapter`

My last gradle(app) file :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    /* Firebase SDK */
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'

    /* Firebase UI */
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.2.2'

    /* For Google Play Services */
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
}
```

My last gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they      
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you got any error with above ?

Comment: No, but with the firebase update I would like to know if any dependency has changed to be added ?

Comment: If firebase SDK will update then you need to update firebase dependency only.

Comment: Good! Thank you so much!

Comment: The FirebaseUI documentation has a handy compatibility table between recent Firebase SDK versions and the corresponding FirebaseUI version. See https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries

Comment: You are using the legacy Firebase SDK, `firebase-client-android`.  When you say _recent Firebase update_ do you mean the new 10.x.x. [Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android)?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add this dependency:

```
// FirebaseUI Database only
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'
```

Check here the compatibility [between versions](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/README.md):

```
| FirebaseUI Version | Firebase/Play Services Version |
|--------------------|--------------------------------|
| 1.0.1              | 10.0.0                         |
| 1.0.0              | 9.8.0                          |
| 0.6.2              | 9.8.0                          |
| 0.6.1              | 9.6.1                          |
| 0.6.0              | 9.6.0                          |
| 0.5.3              | 9.4.0                          |
| 0.4.4              | 9.4.0                          |
| 0.4.3              | 9.2.1                          |
| 0.4.2              | 9.2.0                          |
| 0.4.1              | 9.0.2                          |
| 0.4.0              | 9.0.0                          |
```